# how to get EC/IO and GsmBitErrorRate for GSM value in android?

Tags: java, android

On Android, how do I get the GSM network's EC/IO and BitErrorRate values?

I am using the API:

```
signalStrength.getCdmaEcio();
signalStrength.getEvdoEcio();
signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate();
```

But all of these return -1 value.

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you, and I've been searching information, and I found out that `GSM` and `CDMA` are different technologies, `EVDO` works over `CDMA`, so if you are using a `UMTS (GSM)` SIM card the `signalStrength.getCdmaEcio();` `signalStrength.getEvdoEcio()` will `return -1`, because you are working with a different technology.
 I'm a little confused about the BER measure too. Anyway, I hope this helps you. If I find out the way I'll let you know.

Miquel